# Слово "or" в фильтре вопросов для выбора меток

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, метки, фильтрация-вопросов

Заметил что нет перевода для слова "или":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

более подробную информацию можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&tagMode=Watched&edited=true). Но пока почему-то не нашел в traducir данную строку. Могу ошибаться, но по-моему где-то читал что этих строк нет в туле для переводов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И не должно быть: `или` вместо `or` в запросе не сработает.

Comment: так и что делать получается? или оно тащится с другого места тащится? я просто пробовал и `or` и `или`, либо я не понял как работать с такими строками)

Comment: `or` - это часть запроса. Если вместо `[c#] or [java]` написать `[c#] или [java]`, то вместо вопросов с любой из меток будет найдены вопросы с обеими метками одновременно и словом `или`.